# MySQL query for multi JOIN two tables on multiple colums

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I have a mysql query which interact from 2 tables, 'properties' and 'offers'.

The 'offers' table has can match a record in the property table by either referring to a specific record by a unique code or by the county or region the property is located.

Here's an example of my query...

```
SELECT *, ROUND(((3959 * acos(cos(radians(51.1080390)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(-4.1610140)) + sin(radians(51.1080390)) * sin( radians(latitude)))) * 2),0)/2 AS `distance`
FROM `properties` AS prop
LEFT JOIN `offers` ON prop.code = offers.the_property
LEFT JOIN `offers` AS offsCnty ON prop.county = offsCnty.the_county
LEFT JOIN `offers` AS offsRgn ON prop.region = offsRgn.the_region
HAVING distance <= 2.5
ORDER BY `sleeps` ASC, `distance` ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

In the offers table the are 3 columns `the_property` / `the_county` / `the region` are crucial for linking the appropriate offer with the property/ies. If an offer is to be applied to the entire county, the field `the_property` is blank, otherwise if an offer is for a specific property this field contains the unique property code.

I thought that by using multiple JOIN's would be the solution, however when the any of the 3 main `offer` fields are empty the join returns 'NULL' for the `offers` table fields.

How can this be resolved??

Many thanks

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` means that if there's no row that matches the `ON` condition, it should fill it in with `NULL`. But as long as it matches one of the 3 joins, you should get non-null values in that set of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two tables and specify your extra join conditions in the join clause or the where clause

```
SELECT *, ROUND(((3959 * acos(cos(radians(51.1080390)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(-4.1610140)) + sin(radians(51.1080390)) * sin( radians(latitude)))) * 2),0)/2 AS `distance`
FROM `properties` AS prop
LEFT JOIN `offers` ON prop.code = offers.the_property 
       OR prop.county = offers.the_county 
       OR prop.region = offers.the_region
HAVING distance <= 2.5
ORDER BY `sleeps` ASC, `distance` ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: I think it should be `OR`, not `AND`.

Comment: But I'm not sure this is right, because then it can match multiple rows in `offers`, and he just wants a single row per property.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance @Barmar @DevZer0 :), regarding your point about if multiple offers exist for a particular property record/row, either by matching the `the_county` or `the_property`, would it be possible to do a COUNT(*) as a dynamic column to count the offers, then i will just display the first offer and show more offers are available for the particular property.

Comment: Getting the first row of the group is a real pain in MySQL, because it doesn't have a `TOP` function.

Comment: Using a simple COUNT(id) with GROUP BY is now returning a tally of offers. Thanks for your help on the multiple joins! Im using a combination of OR AND which is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Columns from later offers tables overwrite earlier ones, you need to alias them:

SELECT *, offers.the_property the_property_from_offers, ...

Answer (score 0):

You have three *different* offers tables all with the same field names.  The problem is that MySQL does not allow multiple columns with the same name.

The easiest fix is to change the join to use `or` in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT *, ROUND(((3959 * acos(cos(radians(51.1080390)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(-4.1610140)) + sin(radians(51.1080390)) * sin( radians(latitude)))) * 2),0)/2 AS `distance`
FROM `properties` prop LEFT JOIN
     `offers`
      ON prop.code = offers.the_property or
         (prop.county = offsCnty.the_county and offers.the_property is null) or
         prop.region = offsRgn.the_region
HAVING distance <= 2.5
ORDER BY `sleeps` ASC, `distance` ASC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

If you do use multiple joins, then you should have expressions such as the following in the `select` clause:

```
select coalesce(offers.code, offsCnty.code, offsRgn.code) as code
```

for each column in the offers table.

Comment: MySQL allows multiple columns with the same names, it prefixes them with the table alias in the results. However, the PHP APIs discard the prefixes, so you need to use numeric column indexes to access them all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most specific offer to take precedence, I think you have to write it like this:

```
SELECT prop.*,
       COALESCE(offers.col1, offsCnty.col1, offsRgn.col1) col1,
       COALESCE(offers.col2, offsCnty.col2, offsRgn.col2) col2,
       ...,
       <huge formula> distance
FROM `properties` AS prop
LEFT JOIN `offers` ON prop.code = offers.the_property
LEFT JOIN `offers` AS offsCnty ON prop.county = offsCnty.the_county
LEFT JOIN `offers` AS offsRgn ON prop.region = offsRgn.the_region
HAVING distance <= 2.5
ORDER BY `sleeps` ASC, `distance` ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```